# Fastest way to free BufferedImage memory

Tags: java, memory, bufferedimage

What is the fastest way to save a BufferedImage to disk (in order to free memory)?

My Java application processes loads of images (an image is loaded to memory every ~300ms). Most of those images are discarded (gc) quite immediately, but every once in a while I need to save an image.

Of course, keeping those in RAM is not a good idea, for it eats up an average 2GB JVM in minutes, and crushes the application, so I tried saving it to disk. The problem is, saving it with `ImageIO.write(img, "PNG", file)` is not sufficient enough, because it sometimes takes (on my i7 machine) 5-10 second per 12MB image to process and save, and still doesn't free the memory fast enough.

Is there another format that might perform faster?

#### EDIT:

I don't care to lower resolution or loose image data at reasonable level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PNG is notorious slow in ImageIO. You might try getting the underlying readers and writers.
Maybe write a JPEG instead with hight quality. [Alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293556/looking-for-a-faster-alternative-to-imageio).

Can't you store the input files as File first, so writing with ImageIO is not needed.

For completeness sake: if you da a `BufferedImage.getGraphics()` do not forget the `dispose()`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into the alternatives. The input isn't a file, it gets loaded from a camera connected via USB directly into RAM, and passed to me as a `BufferedImage` object...